# Namespace Secret not available on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to retrieve a cookie on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ with pycookiecheat since pycookiecheat doesn't work on windows. The reason I want to do this is that I need to bypass a login that has multiple steps.

```
from pycookiecheat import chrome_cookies
import requests

url = 'google.com'

cookies = chrome_cookies(url)
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)

print(r.text)
```

But there's an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Homeworker.py", line 7, in <module>
    cookies = chrome_cookies(url)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycookiecheat/pycookiecheat.py", line 199, in chrome_cookies
    config = get_linux_config(browser)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycookiecheat/pycookiecheat.py", line 133, in get_linux_config
    gi.require_version("Secret", "1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 129, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Secret not available
>>> %Run Homeworker.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Homeworker.py", line 7, in <module>
    cookies = chrome_cookies(url)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycookiecheat/pycookiecheat.py", line 199, in chrome_cookies
    config = get_linux_config(browser)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycookiecheat/pycookiecheat.py", line 133, in get_linux_config
    gi.require_version("Secret", "1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 129, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Secret not available
```

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution yet?